# How may I calculate the "effective transfer integral" in free electronic-structure software?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, electronic-structure, gamess

I would like to calculate the following four quantities in a free electronic structure program:

\begin{alignat}{2}\tag{1}
e_1&=\langle\phi_1|H^{KS}|\phi_1\rangle,\\
e_2&=\langle\phi_2|H^{KS}|\phi_2\rangle,\tag{2}\\
J&=\langle\phi_1|H^{KS}|\phi_2\rangle ~~~~~~~&\textrm{(charge transfer integral),}\tag{3}\\
S&=\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle &\textrm{(overlap integral),}\tag{4}
\end{alignat}

Alternatively, if thee's a program that can *directly* calculate the effective transfer integrals $J_{\text{eff}}$ from monomer **A** to monomer **B** within dimer **AB** by:
$$J_{\text{eff}}=\frac{J-S\cdot (e_1+e_2)/2}{1-S^2},\tag{5}$$

then that would be even better!

In the above equations, $\phi_1$ is the LUMO or HOMO of monomer **A**, $\phi_2$ is the LUMO or HOMO of monomer **B**.

Can someone give me a step-by-step tutorial to obtain the quantity $J_{\textrm{eff}}$ or the four quantities needed in order to calculate it manually? I would like to do this in free software, preferably GAMMES(US), but being able to do it in any free software would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know if GAMESS can do it directly, but I have to imagine it can print the Fock and overlap matrices, allowing you to compute $J_\text{eff}$ manually.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!!

Comment: Also, a related publication about computing couplings for bridged dimers: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.7b00431. You can treat the monomers as separate, but this would also allow you to treat possible overlapping fragments.

Comment: Is there a reason why it must be done in GAMESS?

Comment: @NikeDattani The reason for using GAMESS is that it is free and supports many computational methods. If you use any other free software for this purpose, please, let me know.

Comment: @Tyberius  thank you for the paper 10.1021/acs.jctc.7b00431! It clarifies base theoretic concepts, but I am looking for a tutorial with simple examples.

Comment: Perhap change the question to ask how to do this in free software so that more people can answer. OpenMOLCAS, CFOUR, PySCF, Psi4, MRCC, and many others are free, so you would have 6 times as many people available to answer if you also allowed answers for those listed.

Comment: How did this go? Have you found an answer now? It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue since it's been there for more than 11 months now! Please update us!

Comment: @Alexey Mark Perri is co-organizer of https://chemcompute.org/gamess including *in silico* experiments with GAMESS (e.g., an earlier presentation in 2014JChemEduc2206, https://doi.org/10.1021/ed5004228). *Speculation:* maybe it is something he would consider for his set of experiments for physical chemistry, or indicate an other vernue/program.